# WSO2 EI - Disable collecting statistics for specific component types

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'm looking to disable collecting statistics for all sequences and mediators in WSO2 EI. I still want to collect statistics about service calls and what not but discard
unwanted statistics about sequences and mediators contained in those services (which is a lot of unnecessary data).

I'm aware that apart from enabling/disabling statistics for specific services, you can also disable statistics for specific sequences, which would also mean not collecting stats about mediators contained in those sequences. However, in our project some services only contain mediators and not sequences.

So far we've tried adding booleans into *synapse.properties* file

```js
mediation.flow.statistics.collect.proxy=true
mediation.flow.statistics.collect.api=true
mediation.flow.statistics.collect.mediator=false
mediation.flow.statistics.collect.sequence=false
mediation.flow.statistics.collect.resource=true
mediation.flow.statistics.collect.endpoint=true
```

and editing *reportEntryEvent()* and 
 *reportChildEntryEvent()* methods in [org.apache.synapse.aspects.flow.statistics.collectors.OpenEventCollector.java file](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/aspects/flow/statistics/collectors/OpenEventCollector.java). For example if incoming *componentType* is mediator, I quit the *reportChildEntryEvent()* method assuming it would stop the statistic collection process. However this logic doesn't seem to be correct as I still receive mediator statistics in my Stream Processor.

This statistic handling is probably being managed also somewhere else but I actually struggle to see where and what exactly in the *wso2-synapse* code should I edit to achieve this behavior.

Thanks for any reply.